# SQL - Creating a table with the name as a result of a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to create a table in SQL with the following requirements.

I have a table X with two cols, (primary key, value)

Every time, I add a new value to the above table, I create a new table with the name value.

So if there are 10 rows in table X, then we need to have 10 tables with names in the values field.

---

Let me try to explain the situation.
I have a category A and I need to define it.
The subsets of A can include {a1, a2, a3, ..... until infinity}

All the subsets have a different definition but are uniquely identified a property B.

B can be directly A, or a subset A with the definition holding true. I am not sure how to design it. I am using postgresql

---

So I am taking cues from  a_horse_with_no_name and think that this can be a table structure.

```html
Table A 
<table border="1">
  <td> primary_key </td>
  <td> B1 </td>
  <td> B2 </td>
  <td> hstore - attribute </td>
</table>
```

Now what store should act like is similar to a tree.

hstore - attribute -> { a1 : {c1,c2,c3...}, a2 :{d1,d2,d3..}, .... }

C and D are structures here with multiple or single values. So if I am to use an hstore, is it possible to use something like a 2d array or something similar. It seems that it is possible from the following link.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html

I think this is certainly a better approach. Can you please check and comment.
and so on..

Comment: That's a strange requirement. You mean if your table have 1M rows .. you want to create 1M tables? that's awful.

Comment: Well one job will be to protect table X with necessary privileges. Not everyone can actually add rows to table X, only a selected few.

Comment: I have tried updating what I need, can you check that please and see if there is a solution to it.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `hstore` column that can the dynamic attributes

Comment: The new scripting feature is a nice gimmick, but **useless** to provide a table definition. Provide the `CREATE TABLE` statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not do this. And should not.

edit: So, if you want subsets of a super set where all items are similar, you should create a column called 'parent_id' and reference the super set in that column.

Comment: I have tried updating what I need, can you check that please and see if there is a solution to it.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad idea, but yes, you can do that. Might need to get a bit creative to do it depending on what SQL you are using. You will most likely have to make a stored procedure, that creates a new table with it taking a name parameter. Then you can create a trigger on insert to call stored procedure, so every time a new value is inserted a table is created.

Answer (score 0):

this practice is not nice to me. I think you should try another way solve your problem.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you check the latest comments, I mean I know it is not nice, hence I asked the question and am willing to discuss it